# Decision trees & continuous-valued attributes

Tags: attributes, tree, continuous

how does a decision tree handle continuous valued attributes? I know that attributes such as `sex` will have 2 arcs denoting `male` or `female`. But how about continuous valued attributes such as `age`? It is not possible to create arcs for each possible value? Does it create age-range sets? For example having 3 sub-branches labeled as `<18`, `<30`, `>30`? If so how does it decide on the creation of these age-groups?

Comment: My.suggestion is you can try binary tree because you mentioned decision, it means comparing between two values at a time and so binary tree would do your case

Comment: I am not trying to find the optimal method to implement a task like that. I am trying to figure out how decision trees handle continuous data

Answer (score 1):

Some algorithms like CART evaluates all possible splits using Gini Index or other impurity functions.
You just sort the attributes and look at the impurity of each split.
The drawback of the method is that it is greedy, you need to look at every possible split.
[See image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olEZb.png)